# xmlElement parser need in c#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I need to simple xml parser like below.

```
xmlNode root=xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
root.appendChild(xmlElement.Parse("<book name='ff'>sample </book>");
```

is there any parser library or extension method like this
`.Parse("<book name='ff'>sample </book>")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using .Net 3.5, you can use the [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) class to do exactly this.  Check out the documentation for [**XElement.Parse()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse.aspx).

Comment: how to convert from XElement to xmlElement

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the newer Linq-to-Xml system in System.Xml.Linq. There is an XElement.Parse(string xml) function.